# Json Serialization, как правильно достать данные из гетерогенного массива?

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api

Хочу вытянуть ID групп ВК, у которых в названии есть буква "а".
Отправляю запрос и получаю ответ:

```
{  
    "response":[  
        747369,
        {  
            "gid":60386075,
            "name":"Мың бір оқиға [K-POP]",
            "screen_name":"kazanonim",
            "is_closed":0,
            "type":"page",
            "is_admin":0,
            "is_member":0,
            "photo":"http:\/\/cs631116.vk.me\/v631116892\/bfa5\/mv5UyEdPfz8.jpg",
            "photo_medium":"http:\/\/cs631116.vk.me\/v631116892\/bfa4\/EEzzOElvS78.jpg",
            "photo_big":"http:\/\/cs631116.vk.me\/v631116892\/bfa2\/ktxcZIgNLVU.jpg"
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

Но дальше у меня проблема, не могу достать правильно данные, если я делаю как в коде ниже, то мне мешает : `747369` - количество групп у которых есть буква "а" в названии. Я не знаю как обработать его, в результате получаю ошибку

> newtonsoft.json.jsonserializationexception error converting value 747369 ...

```
public void Reader2(string r)
{
     Json2.RootObject groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json2.RootObject>(r);
     foreach (var c in groups.items)
        {
          textBox1.Text += c.screen_name  + Environment.NewLine;
        }
}


public class Json2
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string screen_name { get; set; }
        public int is_closed { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int is_admin { get; set; }
        public int is_member { get; set; }
        public string photo_50 { get; set; }
        public string photo_100 { get; set; }
        public string photo_200 { get; set; }
    }
     public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Попробовал через http://json2csharp.com/ создать класс:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> response { get; set; }
}

Json2.RootObject groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json2.RootObject>(r);
foreach (var c in groups.response)
{
    textBox1.Text += c + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

И вот результат:

```
{
  "gid": 60386075,
  "name": "Мың бір оқиға [K-POP]",
  "screen_name": "kazanonim",
  "is_closed": 0,
  "type": "page",
  "is_admin": 0,
  "is_member": 0,
  "photo": "http://cs631116.vk.me/v631116892/bfa5/mv5UyEdPfz8.jpg",
  "photo_medium": "http://cs631116.vk.me/v631116892/bfa4/EEzzOElvS78.jpg",
  "photo_big": "http://cs631116.vk.me/v631116892/bfa2/ktxcZIgNLVU.jpg"
}
```

Как достать теперь из него данные?
Или если возможно, то как можно избежать ошибку в первом случае?

Comment: К какому методу API обращаетесь?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov groups.search

Comment: странно. Почему тогда приведенный вами JSON кардинально отличается от того, который этот метод [должен возвращать](https://vk.com/dev/groups.search)?

Comment: @SergeyRufanov потому что версия API ниже 5.0. По вашей же ссылке об этом написано.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а.. ясно.. Непонятно правда зачем работать именно с ней? Последние версии десериализуются без всяких извращений.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov да и правда. Я затупил. Сразу нужно было последнюю API брать. И все без проблем.

Comment: Спасибо что указали на ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимые свойства можно найти с помощью JSONPath

```
// #r "\Newtonsoft.Json\6.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\json.txt");
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var o in jo.SelectTokens("..screen_name"))    // JSONPath
  if (o.ToString().Contains("a"))
     Console.WriteLine(o.Parent.Parent["gid"] + " " + o);
```

Результат

```
60386075 kazanonim
```

Для следующего json в файле C:\Temp\json.txt

```
{  
  "response":[  
    747369,
    {  
      "gid":60386075,
      "name":"Мың бір оқиға [K-POP]",
      "screen_name":"kazanonim",
      "is_closed":0,
      "type":"page",
      "is_admin":0,
      "is_member":0,
      "photo":"http:\/\/cs631116.vk.me\/v631116892\/bfa5\/mv5UyEdPfz8.jpg",
      "photo_medium":"http:\/\/cs631116.vk.me\/v631116892\/bfa4\/EEzzOElvS78.jpg",
      "photo_big":"http:\/\/cs631116.vk.me\/v631116892\/bfa2\/ktxcZIgNLVU.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Мың бір оқиға [K-POP]`. Хм. В моей голове не связывается что-то.

Comment: @VladD _"Мың бір оқиға ... В моей голове не связывается что-то"_ -- это казахский, если верить автоопределению языка в гуглтранслейт

Comment: Угу, похож. Но метка K-POP указывает на корейский. Хотя... :)

Answer (score 1):

Перед десериализацией можно получить ответ сервера в виде дерева и отредактировать. Примерно так:

```
var jroot = JObject.Parse(r);
var jresponse = (JArray)jroot["response"];
jresponce.RemoveAt(0);
var root = jroot.ToObject<Json2.RootObject>();
```

Если же это число также нужно, то можно поступить так:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<JToken> response { get; set; }
}

// ...

Json2.RootObject groups = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json2.RootObject>(r);
foreach (var c in groups.response)
{
    if (c is JObject)
    {
        var item = c.ToObject<Json2.Item>();
        // ...
    }
    if (c is JValue) 
    {
        var count = (int)c;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант подходит, но получаю ошибку "Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" в VK.exe

Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: @LittleFox и что дальше? Что говорит отладчик? Что показывает стектрейс?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, похоже автор просто перешел на использование более свежей версии API Вконтакте, да и всё - ибо там уже никакой гетерогенности нету :)