# Десериализация многих разных JSON на C#

Tags: c#, json, сериализация

Есть около сотни (в будущем больше) JSON. Каждый JSON имеет свою структуру. Необходимо их все десериализовать. Пытаюсь использовать стандартный класс **DataContractJsonSerializer**, пользуюсь [этой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) схемой.

При создании экземпляра класса нужно передавать ему тип сериализуемых или десериализуемых экземпляров

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
```

Как я уже сказал, у меня много разных типов, но метод, осуществляющий десериализацию, один. У меня есть строковые параметры с именами классов, описывающих структуру JSON, например: "Person", "Address" и прочее.

Как их подставить в конструктор **DataContractJsonSerializer** так, чтобы не писать сотню кейсов? Возможно ли это стандартными методами?

Пробовал [это](http://blog.vkuznetsov.ru/posts/2011/08/06/csharp-preobrazovanie-stroki-v-universalnyj-tip-generic-type#.Vqs4IoWLSUk), но не работает.

Как вообще такие задачи решаются в промышленной среде?

В интернете полно примеров с одним жестко заданным JSON, но про много разных нигде не нашел.

Comment: _"чтоб не писать сотню кейсов?"_ -- если структура json разная и сложная, то для поиска и извелечения данных можно использовать jsonpath. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486973/196972)

Comment: "В промышленной среде" всё зависит от решаемой задачи. Что за задачу то хотите решить в итоге? Это самое главное, и вы этого не описали совсем. "Хочу десериализовать всё и сразу, как-то универсально" - это вообще не задача, это лишь описание придуманного вами решения неизвестно какой проблемы.

Comment: Приведите пример json'a

Comment: Сергей, модератор потер немного исходный текст, убрав лишнее и в итоге получилось не совсем понятно. Суть проблемы заключается в том, что в процессе взаимодействия с удаленным API возвращается много разных JSON-ок, Каждая описана своим классом. Необходимо их десериализовать, но не писать же свой метод Decode под каждый тип ответа от API. Вот и интересовался как написать общий метод Decode, принимающий любую из описанных JSON, ведь внутри него нужно создавать DataContractJsonSerializer, который жестко привязывается к определенному типу JSON. Надеюсь понятней получилось.

Comment: Мстислав, например { "access_token":"13a85707de16fbb1c290250872f30e0b", "error": {
"code": "0000", "text": "ok" }, "duration": 0.025489807128906 }

Comment: @Олег мне кажется, или вам попросту нужен `Generic` метод?

Comment: Мстислав, мне кажется Вы правы. Попробую покопать в сторону дженериков. В C# неделю как, до Вашего комментария не знал про них.

Comment: @Олег с помощью JSON.NET можно сделать так: `var myNewObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вам изначально известно, какой объект представлен в json'e, то вам достаточно воспользоваться `Generic`-методом для дессериализации:

```
var myNewObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: Это хорошо, если тип известен _заранее_. А что если на запрос «дайте метаданные файла» может прийти `{ "error" : "file not found" }`, `{ "type" : "mp3", properties : { "bitrate" : 320, "Artist" : "Michael Jackson" } }` или `{ "type" : "avi", properties : { "duration" : 3900, "Title" : "Ну погоди", "Audio languages" : [ "ru-RU", "en-US", "cn-ZH" ] } }`?

Comment: @VladD если вы действительно не знаете, как правильно обрабатывать такие ответы, задайте вопрос, я напишу вам ответ.

Comment: Мне казалось, что я знаю. Но мне было бы интересно, если бы вы подсказали в двух словах здесь.

Comment: @VladD для `properties` определяется аттрибут : `JsonConverter`, реализуется конвертер : `JsonConverter`, пропертя делается интерфейсом. Поле error может быть включено, или же ответ можно дать статус кодом.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду что-то такое: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/276994? Мне кажется, это по сути то же самое — просто тест инкапсулирован в конвертере, а не в методе десериализации. Разве нет?

Comment: @VladD по ссылке смысл такой же. Только если вы не обратили внимания, то там происходит определение класса по признаку, и выполняет дессериализация, у вас же она ручная. Там вполне нормальное, промышленное решение. Может быть сегодня вечером напишу более правильный пример. Ваше же решение с точки зрения архитектуры и поддержки - совсем не очень, так решают проблему джуниоры.

Comment: Ну, извините, решаю как умею :) Наверное, в вашу компанию меня бы не взяли. Гора классов, которые ещё надо и поддерживать в консистентном состоянии, даже если надо вытащить один атрибут, может быть и является профессиональным, «энтерпрайзным» решением, но уж точно не является хорошим решением для случая, когда реальное дерево объектов не требуется.

Comment: @VladD у меня вопрос, а вы в крупном коммерческом проекте решали аналогичную задачу? Неужели решали задачу так же как предложили в своем ответе?

Comment: Вопрос в том, _какая_ задача. Если стоит задача получить полный ответ как структуру данных, решение одно. Если стоит задача получить фиксированную часть данных, решение другое.

Comment: @VladD вопрос автором поставлен достаточно однозначно. Это уже вы придумали дополнительные условия, в виде частичного чтения, и неоднозначности json'a.

Comment: Возможно, моя интерпретация условия неверна. А возможно и верна. Тем лучше, что на вопрос дано несколько разных ответов.

Comment: Мстислав, в моем случае MyClass - это строка. Компилятор ругается что я пытаюсь строку использовать как тип. Такая-же проблема была и с коробочным методом. Или я не так Вас понял?

Comment: @Олег `MyClass` - это тип(класс) в который преобразуется строка из `json`

Comment: @Мстислав это я понял, спасибо. Есть проблема в другом. Я создаю метод `Json.Decode(string jsonString, string uri)` в который приходит собственно сама json строка и uri, по которому обращались, например `"login"`. Описываем одноименные классы `login`, `activate`, `logout` и прочие. В самом методе `Decode` мне нужна некая фабрика, которая из строки `"login"` делает тип `login` и подставляет в `DeserializeObject<login>`. Но мне не хочется писать длиннющий `switsh case` так как видится это дело не красивым. Можно ли как-то привести строку `"login"` к одноименному классу и подставить в метод?

Comment: покажите `json`

Comment: Если речь об ответе из API, то типичный ответ - `{ "access_token":"13a85707de16fbb1c290250872f30e0b", "error": { "code": "0000", "text": "ok" }, "duration": 0.025489807128906 }`. Поле `error` и `duration` одинаково для всех ответов, остальные данные представлены одномерными полями в зависимости от запроса. Если речь о классе Json - то там пока один единственный метод `Decode(string jsonString, string uri)` в котором пока одна строка `return JObject.Parse(json)`. Сделал пока по методу VladD, чтоб разработка не стояла, но стремлюсь к Best Practice.

Comment: @Олег я когда то очень давно решал похожую задачу когда реализовывал общение с Zabbix'ом, там общение происходит с помощью json.rpc. Вот ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/Bezarius/ZabbixApi должно помочь.

Comment: @Олег вам нужно внимательно рассмотреть метод: https://github.com/Bezarius/ZabbixApi/blob/master/ZabbixClient.cs#L163

Comment: То, что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: @Олег если вы решили свою проблему и мой ответ вам помог, то поставьте галку напротив моего ответа, что бы другие участники не пытались найти еще варианты решения вашего вопроса :)

Answer (score 5):

Вам стоит воспользоваться JSON.NET ([вот так](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) подключается к проекту).

После этого, чтобы не выписывать тип, вы можете десериализовать в [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string json = "{\n" +
              "    \"access_token\":\"13a85707de16fbb1c290250872f30e0b\",\n" +
              "    \"error\":\n" +
              "    { \"code\": \"0000\", \"text\": \"ok\" },\n" +
              "    \"duration\": 0.025489807128906\n" +
              "}";
var o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Если вы знаете имя свойства, им можно легко воспользоваться:

```
var accessToken = (string)o["access_token"]; // "13a85707de16fbb1c290250872f30e0b"
var errorCode = (int)o["error"]["code"];     // 0
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)o["duration"]); // {00:00:00.0250000}
```

Comment: Это ну совсем не промышленное решение :\

Comment: @МстиславПавлов: А что в нём непромышленного? Не в стиле Java EE, нету фабрики фабрик классов? По условию, имена полей доступны как строки.

Comment: промышленный код, он на то и промышленный, должен быть надежным, а значит тестируемым. Такой подход в промышленной разработке совершенно неприемлем.

Comment: Десериализация объектов принципально не может быть «надёжной», строка может вообще не оказаться валидным JSON'ом. Так что понятно, что весь разбор нужно помещать в большой try/catch. А вот нетестируемости в коде не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо, хотелось бы пойти путями "из коробки", но если не получится, воспользуюсь этим.

Comment: Если речь идет о промышленной разработке, то все изменения в формате передаваемых данных строго фиксируются и об этом заранее сообщается всем партнерам, которые являются пользователем сервиса. Я участвовал в разработке промышленной системы, которая являлась агрегатором данных с самых различных систем, и уж поверьте, ниразу к такому решению мы не прибегали, хотя интеграций с более чем десятком других систем, которые в свою очередь интегрируются с другими поставщиками данных. Везде все регламентировано.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов: То, что вы предлагаете, как раз и есть «заводите по типу данных для каждого типа ответа» — то, чего автор вопроса старается избежать.

Comment: @VladD где автор написал, что он старается избежать создания множества классов для каждого ответа?(что неизбежно в энтерпрайзе)

Comment: @МстиславПавлов: «Как я уже сказал, у меня много разных типов, но метод, осуществляющий десериализацию, один. У меня есть строковые параметры с именами классов, описывающих структуру JSON, например: "Person", "Address" и прочее. // Как их подставить в конструктор DataContractJsonSerializer так, чтобы не писать сотню кейсов? Возможно ли это стандартными методами?»

Comment: @VladD все же мне кажется, что метод и класс таки разные вещи :)

Answer (score 3):

Если приложению доступна сборка, в которой находится нужный класс, и у вас есть имя этого класса, вы можете загрузить assembly, найти в ней соответствующий тип, а затем передать его в конструктор `DataContractJsonSerializer`:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

AssemblyName asn = new AssemblyName("Assembly.Name");
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(asn);

Type tp = assembly.GetType("Person");
if (tp == null)
    throw new TypeAccessException();

var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(tp);
object person = ser.ReadObject(stream); // => Person
```

Comment: Это в случае, если в assembly такой тип _есть_.

Comment: Компилятор ругается:
"Assembly" не содержит определение для "GetExecutingAssembly"

Comment: Типа Type тоже нет. У меня прога под Win Phone 8.1

Comment: @Олег, чтобы видеть `Type` добавьте `using System;`. Не очень хорошо знаком с платформой Win Phone 8.1, но вот такой код (поправил ответ) скомпилировался (WP8.1 + .net4.5).

Comment: @i-one Исключение типа System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly.Name, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Олег, вместо `"Assembly.Name"` вам нужно указать имя сборки - так, как она _у вас_ называется. Также имя типа может потребоваться полное, вместе с namespace, к которому он принадлежит, напр. `MyNamespace.MyClasses.Person`.

Comment: Понимаю, что нужно идти выпрямлять руки, но, к сожалению, никак не получается с этим подходом. Бросает исключение Value cannot be null. Если написать полное имя типа, то такое-же исключение как и до этого. В принципе получилось сделать тоже самое через `public T Decode<T> (string jsonString)` Продолжу копать в этом направлении. Спасибо Вам за отклик.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static T FromJson<T>(this string objString)
{
    var stream = objString.GetMemoryStream();

    stream.Position = 0;

    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    return (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
}

public static string ToJson<T>(this T obj)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);
    stream.Position = 0;

    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);

    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Одно НО: не работает с многомерными массивами.

Comment: Почему вы используете MemoryStream вместо более логичных в такой ситуации StringWriter/StringReader?